# Dynamically choose colors for barplot

Tags: r, plot, shiny

I am making an app using shiny package for R data analysis.

I am having trouble in giving the values for `color` attribute for `barplot` function. I am taking two columns from the user and I am applying the function nvalues that does the trick for default colors.. but what If I want to have my own array of custom colors and use only some of them as per column's requirement.

here is my shiny file

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$myplot<-renderPlot({          
    c1<-input$cname1
    c2<-input$cname2
    clm1<-smpl[,c1]
    clm2<-smpl[,c2]
    counts<-table(clm1,clm2)
    View(counts)
    n<-nlevels(clm1)
    barplot(counts,beside=TRUE,col=c(1:n),legend = rownames(counts))                    
  })
})
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking here. Are you asking for a function to choose among a list of colors?

Comment: I am asking that if counts has n levels then n colors should be selected from a vector of color that I define and not all the colors in that vector.

Answer (score 0):

As with all `base` plotting functions, assign a vector of colors as you desire.

```
barplot(some_data,col=c('red','orange','yellow','green','blue'))
```

or

```
barplot(some_data,col=rainbow(10))
```

and so on.   The `col` vector recycles as necessary.

Comment: what if the levels in the column are fewer than the vector. It uses it for the next subgroup in a barplot. thats not good

Comment: @apps92 then specify the index, e.g. `col=rainbow(10)[1:n]`